# What would happen if we don't unregister a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I dynamically register a **BroadcastReceiver** which is an inner class of the **Activity** in `onCreate()` and don't unregister it anywhere within the code.

Now suppose `finish()` is called and after some time, the app is opened again. Would the new receiver object be used? Considering that the old receiver object with same intent filter might still be in the memory ...

Comment: If your Activity finishes without unregistering, it'll leak the Receiver, and you'll get a nasty message in your logcat. If you start the Activity again, the Receiver will be a new, different instance.

Comment: @MikeM.Would the leaked receiver receive broadcasts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you forget unregister receiver inner Activity Class, the Android system reports a leaked broadcast receiver error.

But if the BroadcastReceiver is dynamically registered by the Service, it will not be leaked if you make sure it is unregistered when the Service is destroyed. After the Service is restarted (after being killed by the system) it will try to update once again. When this  update fails you will register the BroadcastReceiver once again to listen for connection changes.