# What if I don't UnregisterReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-powermanager

What happens if I don't unregister a receiver? Will it slow down my app or causes app crash or throws some sort of exception? I need this receiver to be reigstered all time, even if app is closed:

```
this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
             PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED));
```

Comment: Anstered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022786/what-would-happen-if-we-dont-unregister-a-broadcastreceiver

Comment: Where are you calling `registerReceiver`? and what is `this` in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It depends:*

If you don't do that when it was registered in an **Activity** (by manifest), Android OS will report `leaked broadcast service error`.

But if the BroadcastReceiver is **dynamically** registered by the Service, it will not be leaked *if you make sure it is unregistered when the Service is destroyed*.

If it was killed by system and you register it again it will `update the previous one`.